# I cant get able to get 100% code coverage

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test, code-coverage, failing-tests

Controller  estension Class: **BOMPage_Class**

```
public class BOMPage_Class {
    public list<Harness__c> HRlist {get; set;}
    Public list<Raw_Material__c>  RMlist {get; set;}
    Public Bill_Of_Material__c BOM {get; set;}
    public BOMPage_Class(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        HRlist = new list<Harness__c>();
        RMlist = new list<Raw_Material__c>();
        BOM = new Bill_Of_Material__c();
        HRlist= [select Bill_Of_Materials__c,Harness_Purchase_Order__c,
                 Harness_PO_Number__c,Name,
                 Customer_PN__c,Quantity__c,
                 Drawing_REV__c,Harness_Comments__c
                 from Harness__c
                 where id=:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
        if (HRlist != null && !HRlist.isEmpty() && HRlist.size() > 0) {
            RMlist =[select Item_Description__c,
                     Item_Part_Number__c,Item_Unit__c,
                     Quantity__c,Comments__c,Maker__c from
                     Raw_Material__c
                     where Bill_Of_Materials__c = :HRlist[0].Bill_Of_Materials__c];
            BOM =[select Prepared_By__c,Checked_By__c,
                  Approved__c
                  from Bill_Of_Material__c
                  where Id = :HRlist[0].Bill_Of_Materials__c];
        }
    }
}
```

Test Class:

```
isTest
public class TestBOMPage_Class {

    static testmethod void unitTest() {
        Test.startTest();
        supplier__c sp= new supplier__c(Name='e34231');
        insert SP;

        Items__c I = new Items__c(Supplier__c=SP.id);
        insert I;

        Bill_Of_Material__c BM = new Bill_Of_Material__c(
            Prepared_By__c='Vasanth',
            Checked_By__c='Vasanth',
            Approved__c='Prasanna');
        insert BM;

        Raw_Material__c RM= new Raw_Material__c(
            Comments__c='test',
            Bill_Of_Materials__c=BM.id,
            Items__c=i.id);
        insert RM;

        list<Raw_Material__c> RMlistclass= new list<Raw_Material__c>();
        RMlistclass.add(RM);

        Harness_Purchase_Order__c hp = new Harness_Purchase_Order__c(PO_Number__c='uiwyte');
        insert hp;

        Harness__c a=new Harness__c(
            name='test',
            Bill_Of_Materials__c=BM.id,
            Harness_Purchase_Order__c=hp.id,
            Customer_PN__c='32454324',
            Quantity__c=3,
            Drawing_REV__c='423',
            Harness_Comments__c='443t53');
        insert a;

        list<Harness__c> HRlistclass= [select id,name from Harness__c where id=:a.id];

        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(a);
        BOMPage_Class testAccPlan = new BOMPage_Class(sc);
        testAccPlan.HRlist=HRlistclass;
        testAccPlan.BOM=BM;
        testAccPlan.RMlist=RMlistclass;

        PageReference pageRef = Page.BOMPage;
        pageRef.getParameters().put('id', String.valueOf(a.Id));
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Visualforce page

```
<apex:page standardController="Harness__c" renderAs="PDF" extensions="BOMPage_Class" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" lightningStylesheets="true">
------------------
<apex:page>
```

I cant to able cross test coverage on the above class What ever changes i did in the test class it is not covering thing inside this if loop. A small help could be beneficial.

```
  if(HRlist != null && !HRlist.isEmpty() && HRlist.size()>0){   
  }
```

Thanks for understanding

Comment: After `ApexPages.StandardController` add `ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',a.id);`

Comment: @zaitsman Thanks It worked